# My Code hits to a breakpoint when there is none

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, masm

i'm trying to code a basic calculator in C++ & Assembly. When i try to add two integers, application hits to a breakpoint when there is no breakpoint.

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
extern "C" {int Add(int a, int b);}
extern "C" {int Subtract(int a, int b); }
extern "C" {int Multiply(int a, int b); }
extern "C" {int Divide(int a, int b); }

int main()
{
cout << "Choose one: "<< endl;
cout << "1. Add" << endl;
cout << "2. Subtract" << endl;
cout << "3. Multiply" << endl;
cout << "4. Divide" << endl;
char answer = _getch();

switch (answer) 
{
case '1':
    int x, y;
    cout << "x: ";
    cin >>  x;
    cout << "y:";
    cin >> y;
    cout << x << "+" << y << "=" << Add(x, y) << endl; //Breakpoint hits in this line
    break;
case '2':
    break;
case '3':
    break;
case '4':
    break;
}
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

And here's the assembly part

```
.code
Add PROC
  add ecx, edx
  mov eax, ecx
Add ENDP

Subtract PROC
  neg edx
  add ecx, edx
  mov eax, ecx
Subtract ENDPROC

Multiply ENDP
  imul ecx, edx
  mov eax, ecx
  ret
Multiply ENDP

Divide PROC
  mov r8d, edx
  mov eax, ecx
  cdq
  idiv r8d
  ret
Divide ENDPROC
End
```

What's my mistake? And, not related to topic but, is my assembly part correct? I'm plnning to add other functions but it was very complicated to me. Taking my time to learn.

Comment: `ENDPROC` is not instruction, only assembler directive. Your procedures are not terminated and the CPU will execute following memory as instructions. You are probably seeing crash of this random memory being executed. Add `ret` where appropriate. And use debugger with disassembly view to check yourself, what is being executed, with which values.

Comment: Ah, i realized that, i changed them as ENDP, which i assume as correct. I'm exactly trying to see the register behaviour but i honestly skipped that class and now trying to understand how these things works. Is there any tutorials to make me understand this? I cannot simply google it because i dont honestly know what i'm looking for. *shame*

Comment: `ENP` is probably the same thing as `ENDPROC`, both are only directives of MASM, affecting the compilation, but not producing any instruction. In assembly you have to explicitly change execution flow back to caller by using `ret` instruction (like you do in mul/div subroutines, but not in add/sub). What do you use to edit this? Looks like 64b code with MASM, so are you programming under windows 64b with visual studio? Then google "debugging assembler visual studio 64b" or something similar. I don't use windows for 10+ years, didn't see VS since v6 (very good), so can't help more.

Comment: Check also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for various hints, not sure how much info is for win64 target, but some general tutorials/faqs should be there.

Comment: please don't write the answer into the question. There is a clear separation here between a question and an answer. If you want you can answer your own question. However in this case I feel your question should be closed as a typo error.

Comment: Ah, okay sorry about that. You're right. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's a bit weird but here's the answer:

Thanks to Ped7g, i realized i mistype ENDP as ENDPROC in my assembly codes. Also, i forgot to type "ret" in some required places, which fixed my issue.

But again, sadly, this is not a clear answer if you're having this trouble. Sorry for being noob about this post. It wasn't constructive.

Comment: That's wrongly understood my comment. `ENDP` and `ENDPROC` alias for the same directive as far as I know (I will not check the MASM docs for you, you are using that ...piece of SW...). I was just telling you, that those are not processor instructions, but assembler directives. And in assembly the "procedures" are not done by assembler, but by programmer, by explicitly controlling code flow. The `PROC/ENDP` directives are more like "style" thing for reading source, not relevant much to final machine code produced. The important bit was the missing `ret` INSTRUCTION (making CPU do something).

Comment: The origin of "breakpoint" is actually puzzling a bit, maybe the MASM+VS in debug mode pads space between procedures with `0xCC` to align them, plus to help catch this kind of bugs early. In many other assemblers your code would rather run through add+sub+mul subroutines and find first `ret` there. And most important bit of my "answer" is to learn to use debugger, check what the CPU is doing, why did it stop, where, and in what state. Programming in asm without debugger is hard (I did that as child, and now I'm this kind of OCD-bitter-smartass = part of that due to pain of coding on paper).

Comment: I mean, after programming about 5 years "on paper" with access to computer only for couple of hours weekly, the poor SO Q authors are forever doomed to look "no effort" to me. Like they spend few hours or days over some problem stuck, and they come here, and write incomplete description and expect some understanding. And they have actual physical HW in their hands and state-of-art debuggers. So they can simply try&watch. I had to figure it out on paper, because all the machine did show me was reset screen (didn't had enough time to debug on computer in the 2-3 hours available). Ridiculous. ;)

Comment: @Ped7g: yes, MSVC pads with `int3` (`0xcc`) between functions.  That's a Good Thing in general, even for release mode.  If a mispredicted indirect branch ever speculates into that padding, you want it to just stop speculating along that path, and an instruction like `int3` does that.  IDK if that ever happens in practice, though, and gcc always pads with long NOPs.  If it had a measurable perf benefit, I think other compilers would do it too.  (I did try to measure once, but my test-case was too simple and branch-prediction won.)